# Увеличить размер шрифта в мессенджере Viber для Windows 10

Tags: windows, шрифты, viber

Каким образом можно увеличить размер шрифта в мессенджере Viber для Windows.
В настройках приложения такая возможность отсутствует (версия 8.6.0).

Пример текущей ситуации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Анекдоты крутые) А по делу:

> В самом приложении вайбер менять настройки шрифтов, а также увеличить или уменьшить размер шрифта нельзя, такая функция просто не предусмотрена в этом приложении. Однако изменить размер шрифта в приложении вайбер можно, для этого нужно изменить размер шрифта в настройках вашего смартфона. Например, на андройде нужно открыть настройки и в разделе "устройство" выбрать строку "дисплей" в открывшемся меню ищем строку "размер шрифта", нажимаем на нее и выбираем нужный размер шрифта. После данных манипуляций размер шрифта меняется во всех приложениях и в целом в ОС все надписи будут того размера который вы указали в настройках смартфона.

Цитата от [сюда](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2597351-kak-uvelichit-shrift-v-vajbere.html)

Comment: А ничего, что речь не по поводу смартфонов?

Comment: суть та же, нужно изменить шрифт где то еще. Например, в браузере

Answer (score 1):

Нашла способ! нажимаешь клавишу Win и "+" и пользуешься лупой. Очень удобно - для простого обычного пользователя!))

Comment: Изменение шрифта во всем компе приводит к тому, что читаешь все 24 кеглем, ну зачем это мне?))